# Kendo Grid - PopUp windows not being removed from the DOM

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo grid with a custom popup:

```
columns.Command(commands => 
  {
      commands.Edit();
  }


.Editable(editing => editing.Mode(Kendo.Mvc.UI.GridEditMode.PopUp))
```

Each time I click the edit button the window pops up but when I close it the window is not removed from the DOM.

I saw this post: http://www.telerik.com/forums/popup-windows-do-not-get-removed-from-dom and Telerik says the issue has been fixed.

What are some things that would cause this behavior?

**UPDATED**

This grid is nested in a Kendo TabStrip if that helps. Other than that I don't see anything out of the ordinary. The popup is entirely managed by the grid.

**UPDATED 2**
So I got the un-minimized code for the grid (kendo.grid.min.js, version 2013.3.1119, starting at line 1172), slopped it into my project and modified just the following with the two log statements to verify that destroy is being bound and called:

```
_destroyEditable: function () {
    var that = this;

    var destroy = function () {
    if (that.editable) {
    //  My edit
        console.log("...destroy() called");
        that._detachModelChange();
        that.editable.destroy();
        that.editable = null;
        that._editContainer = null;
    }
};

if (that.editable) {                
    if (that._editMode() === "popup") {
        //  My edit
        console.log("Binding destroy() to 'deactivate'...");
            that._editContainer.data("kendoWindow").bind("deactivate", destroy).close();
        } else {
            destroy();
        }
    }
},
```

Each time I click edit and then close the window I see the expected two messages yet the window is not removed. Here is a screenshot of the debugger:

[image: Debugger window]

The outlined windows are the dom elements generated.

Comment: Closing a window does not remove the DOM, that's the expected behavior for a question of efficiency not having to create it multiple times. The issues is if it gets created multiple times. If you want to remove it (do you really need it?) you should invoke `destroy` method (but I don't think that you really need it)

Comment: I am not creating the window. The grid is creating it when you click the 'Edit' button that gets added next to each row in the grid. Each time I click 'Edit' the window (in reality a new window) pops up. After closing it I can check the debugging tools and see that there is a new window in the DOM. It is not removing the window when it is closed and it is not re-using it on subsequent openings.

Comment: If so, it would be a bug. But take a look into the following code http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/TgDYx/1/ and you will see that the counter of existing windows is either 0 or 1 but never more than that. So it is likely something in your code, something that you are not showing.

Comment: That's why I am asking what sort of things could cause this.

Comment: I would need to see more code. Do you have any `preventDefault` that would prevent KendoUI from disposing the window? What type of events are you managing? are you getting any error in the browser console?

Comment: I don't see any prevent default and no errors in browser. What events are you referring to?

Comment: Example: when you define a Grid, you can define `change`, `save`, ... events. Some might be invoked just before KendoUI code destroys the window. If they fail or the intentionally ask for not continuing with the normal processing (by invoking `preventDefault`) they might have left the window in the DOM (but this is guessing, not being able to see/debug your code I can only guess)

Comment: I don't see anything like that. The events that were being bound to I commented out and the problem still occurs. This is frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much trial and error and deep diving it turns out this problem has to do with our scripts in our site's layout. At some point whomever setup the kendo scripts put in not only the 'kendo.all.min.js' but right after it 'kendo.web.min.js', 'kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js' and then about 10 individual kendo.*.js including the grid.

After viewing this link:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/javascript-dependencies

I realized that the site is creating these objects multiple times. Removing the script references in accordance to the link above resolves the issue.

Comment: Good find, must have been agonizing for you to find the problem.

Comment: It would be nice if some sort of error or console message was emitted when this condition is detected.